# multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a multidimensional array like this

```
$role = array (
                  'Dashboard' => null,
                  'Students' => 
                    array (
                      'Admission' => array ( 0 =>  'Entry' ,1 =>  'Review' , 2 =>  'Approved/Reject'
                       ),
                     'Search' => null,
                     'AdvanceSearch' => null,
                     'Courses' => null
                    ),
                  'HR' => array ('Settings' => null),
                  'Employee Management' => array ( 0 =>  'Entry',1 =>  'Association',2 =>  'Search' ),
                  'Employee Attendance' => null,
                  'Payroll' => array (0 =>  'Generate Pay Slip',1 =>  'Payroll Run' , 2 =>  'Payroll Revert',3 =>  'View Pay Slips'),
                  'Finance' => null,
                  'More' => null);
```

and i want to print this array result in my html as

[image: Here is the wanted solution]

i am trying to do this by using recursion but unable to do that as DIV are not properly closed .. 
 here is the code that i am trying in my html

```
<?php 

                             $child = 0;
                            function RecursiveWrite($array, $child ) {
                                $parent_array_size =  count($array);
                                foreach ($array as $key => $vals) {
                                    if(is_array($vals)){
                                        $inner_array_size = count($vals);
                                        echo "<div class='main clear'><input type='checkbox'/> ".$key." &nbsp; &nbsp; ";
                                        RecursiveWrite($vals,$child);
                                    }else{
                                        $child = 0;
                                        if(is_numeric($key)){
                                            echo " &nbsp; <div class='left'> &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type='checkbox' class=''/> ".$vals." &nbsp; &nbsp; </div></div>";
                                        }else{
                                            echo "<div class='clear'><input type='checkbox'/> ".$key." </div></div>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    //
                                }
                            }
                            RecursiveWrite($role, $child);
                        ?>
```

here is [working code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ecz6fK#)

How can i get this Any suggestion ... ?

Comment: your input data structure is a bit inconsistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Problem is missing closing div after recursion
Try this Function

```
function RecursiveWrite($array, $child )
{
    $parent_array_size =  count($array);
    foreach ($array as $key => $vals)
     {
        if(is_array($vals))
        {
            $inner_array_size = count($vals);
            echo "<div class='deep'><div class='extra'><input type='checkbox'/> ".$key."</div>";
            RecursiveWrite($vals,$child);
            echo "</div>";
        }
        else
        {
            if(is_numeric($key)){
                echo "<span class='single'><input type='checkbox' class=''/> ".$vals."</span>";
            }else{
                echo "<div class='single'><input type='checkbox'/> ".$key." </div>";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Use This Css

```
<style type="text/css">
    .parent {border: solid 1px #000;}
    .parent div {border: solid 1px #000; margin:5px;}
    .extra {border:0px !important;}
    .single {margin-left:10px !important; border:0px !important;}
    span.single {display:inline-block; margin-left:20px;}
</style>
```

Use this to call your Function

```
<div class="parent"><? RecursiveWrite($role, $child);?></div>
```

Put all the code Provided in one page with your array.

For better Codding standard you should Septate your style html and php for this try your luck ;)

Comment: You provided exactly what i need Thnks @champ

Answer (score 1):

You're not closing the `div` in the right places, when calling the recursion, right after ending the recursion you need to write the ending `div`:

- open div
- run recursion
- close div

As well, you have two unnecessary div closing. Always  make sure you open as many div as you close and vice versa. I've marked the places that needed to be changed in the code.

code:

```
<?php 
    $child = 0;
    function RecursiveWrite($array, $child ) {
        $parent_array_size =  count($array);
        foreach ($array as $key => $vals) {
            if(is_array($vals)){
                $inner_array_size = count($vals);
                echo "<div class='main clear'><input type='checkbox'/> ".$key." &nbsp; &nbsp; ";
                RecursiveWrite($vals,$child);
                echo "</div>"; /* <== ADD THIS */
            }else{
                $child = 0;
                if(is_numeric($key)){
                    echo " &nbsp; <div class='left'> &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type='checkbox' class=''/> ".$vals." &nbsp; &nbsp; </div>"; /* <== REMOVE EXTRA DIV */
                }else{
                    echo "<div class='clear'><input type='checkbox'/> ".$key." </div>";  /* <== REMOVE EXTRA DIV */
                }
            }
            //
        }
    }
    RecursiveWrite($role, $child);
?>
```

you can find a working example at http://codepad.viper-7.com/507rLc

Comment: Champ provided me the exact one which i need .. but i upvoted you also :)